# Failed to load document PHPMailer PDF Base64 string

Tags: php, email, pdf, base64, phpmailer

I want to send PDF document using the BASE64 string. The PDF sends but when you download/open the PDF document in email, it does not load. I tried copy and pasting the string in Chrome and it generates a PDF. How to fix it?

```
if(isset($_POST['pdf'])) {
  $base64String = 'data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKJbrfrOAKMyAwIG9iago8PC9...';
  $phpmailer->addStringAttachment(base64_decode($base64String) 'セラミック矯正治療のご案内.pdf');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will not generate a valid binary attachment, because a complete `data` URL is not a base64 string. Remove the header from the data and decode that, i.e. strip the `data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,` prefix before attempting to decode it.

If you're getting the string from a PHP PDF generator, you should be able to get the binary PDF string directly from that, which you can pass directly into PHPMailer, which will deal with encoding it for you.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. I tried to remove the first few string by using the following code: `$base64String = substr($_POST['pdf'], strlen('data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,'));`